# Shift, fn, ctrl, alt, right and left touchpad isn't working

Tags: touchpad, fn-key, shift, alt, ctrl

My notebook model is HP PROBOOK 640 G1

I Downloaded hp system image manager about a year ago. I extracted it and accidently opened thunderboltfirmware.exe after opening it it showed cmd-like window and some text in it. after 3 days, my touchpad buttons didn't worked correctly. then after 2 weeks. my laptop didn't startup. it was completely dead. i give it to IT professional, but he couldn't solved it. then, i removed the battery and don't used it about a month. then i am able power on it.

but, the touchpad issue wasn't solved. then shift[both], alt[both], ctrl[both] and fn key stopped working. Now i am using the laptop with a mouse and a help of On-Screen Keyboard Software.

PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: Try looking at the comments on this question, as it might help... maybe: [How can I get my ctrl key to work again?](https://superuser.com/questions/871258/how-can-i-get-my-ctrl-key-to-function-again)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page
https://support.hp.com/ch-fr/drivers/selfservice/hp-probook-640-g1-notebook-pc/5405392
and downloads the driver into keyboard mouse drivers and input devices and the first is the HP Hotkey support drivers 
Here, I hope everything's okay.
nice day

Comment: it is not a software problem, i even checked he keyboard in bios

Comment: Have you tried to reset the bios to its default values?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you went into the bios and the keys didn't work either.
Maybe you could try using a USB live key with ubuntu that you can install with rufus and then you'll be sure to know if it's mechanical or software